# LoadLibrary failed for: [sdk_wrapper_dotnet.dll] when calling MIP SDK for labeling a document from Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-information-protection, microsoft-information-protection

I wrote an Azure Function which use C# MIP sdk for labeling documents.
When I run the azure function locally all works fine and the document is labelled.
When I run the azure function in cloud, in the logs I see this error: LoadLibrary failed for: [sdk_wrapper_dotnet.dll].
Have someone encountered this problem before?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I hope I can help.

When deploying in cloud functions, you may need to push both the x86 and x64 SDK binaries with your application. When you do that, you must also provide the location to the correct binaries to the SDK's MIP.Initialize() function.

Check out [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/mipsdk-fileapi-dotnet-onbehalfof/blob/master/MipSdk-FileApi-DotNet-OnBehalfOf/MipSdk-FileApi-DotNet-OnBehalfOf/FileApi.cs#L70) (specifically building the path and MIP.Initialize()).

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/mipsdk-fileapi-dotnet-onbehalfof/blob/master/MipSdk-FileApi-DotNet-OnBehalfOf/MipSdk-FileApi-DotNet-OnBehalfOf/FileApi.cs#L70

Answer (score 0):

This error usually comes when the application does not have the required runtime, or was not built as Release. See [Ensure your app has the required runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/setup-configure-mip#ensure-your-app-has-the-required-runtime) for more information.

Applications built with the MIP SDK require the Visual C++ 2015 or Visual C++ 2017 runtime to be installed, if not already present.

These will only work if the application has been built as Release. If the application is built as Debug, then the Visual C++ runtime debug DLLs must be included with the application or installed on the machine.

[See the FAQ section of the Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/faqs-known-issues)

[image]

Comment: I run the azure function in cloud.So I can't install anything.
And when I publish the azure function in cloud is in release mode.